# Data declaration with no data constructor. Can it be instantiated? Why does it compile?

Tags: haskell, types

Reading one of my Haskell books, I came across the sentence:

> Data declarations *always* create a new type constructor, but may or *may not* create new data constructors.

It sounded strange that one should be able to declare a data type with no data constructor, because it seems that then one could never instantiate the type. So I tried it out. The following data declaration compiles without error.

```
data B = String
```

**How would one create an instance of this type?** Is it possible? I cannot seem to find a way.

I thought maybe a data constructor with name matching the type constructor would be created automatically, but that does not appear to be the case, as shown by the error resulting from attempting to use `B` as a data constructor with the declaration in scope.

```
Prelude> data B = String deriving Show
Prelude> B

<interactive>:129:1: error: Data constructor not in scope: B
```

**Why is this data declaration permitted to  compile if the type can never be instantiated?**
Is it permitted solely for some formal reason despite not having a known practical application?

---

I also wonder whether my book's statement about data types with no constructor might be referring to types declared via the `type` or `newtype` keywords instead of by `data`.

- In the `type` case, type synonyms clearly do not use data
  constructors, as illustrated by the following.

  ```
  Prelude> type B = String
  Prelude>
  ```

  Type synonyms such as this can be instantiated by the constructors of
  the type they are set to. But I am not convinced that this is what my
  book is referring to as type synonyms do not seem to be declaring a new data type as much as
  simply defining an new alias for an existing type.
- In the `newtype` case, it appears that types without data
  constructors cannot be created, as shown by the following error.

  ```
  Prelude> newtype B = String

  <interactive>:132:13: error:
      • The constructor of a newtype must have exactly one field
          but ‘String’ has none
      • In the definition of data constructor ‘String’
        In the newtype declaration for ‘B’
  ```

`type` and `newtype` do not appear to be what the book is referring to, which brings me back to my original question: why it is possible to declare a type using `data` with no data constructor?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> How would one create an instance of this type?

The statement from your book is correct, but your example is not. `data B = String` defines a *type constructor* `B` and a *data constructor* `String`, both taking no arguments. Note that the `String` you define is in the value namespace, so is different from the usual `String` type constructor.

```
ghci> data B = String
ghci> x = String
ghci> :t x
x :: B
```

However, here is an example of a data definition without data constructors (so it cannot be instantiated).

```
ghci> data B
```

Now, I have a new type constructor `B`, but no data constructors to produce values of type `B`. In fact, such a data type is declared in the Haskell `base`: it is called `Void`:

```
ghci> import Data.Void
ghci> :i Void
data Void   -- Defined in ‘Data.Void’
```

> Why is this data declaration permitted to compile if the type can never be instantiated?

Being able to have uninhabited types turns out to be useful in a handful of places. The examples that I can think of right now are mostly passing in such a type as a type parameter to another type constructor. One more practical use case is in streaming libraries like [`conduit`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit).

There is a [`ConduitM i o m r`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.11/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t:ConduitM) type constructor where: `i` is the type of the input stream elements, `o` the type of the output stream elements, `m` the monad in which actions are performed, `r` is the final result produced at the end.

Then, it defines a [`Sink`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.11/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t:Sink) as

```
type Sink i m r = ConduitM i Void m r
```

since a `Sink` should never output any values. `Void` is a compile time guarantee that `Sink` *cannot* output any (non-bottom) values.

Much like [`Identity`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Identity.html#t:Identity), `Void` is mostly useful in conjunction with other abstractions.

> ... type synonyms clearly do not use data constructors

Yes, but they are not defining type constructors either. Synonyms are just some surface-level convenience renaming. Under the hood, nothing new is defined.

> In the newtype case, it appears that types without data constructors cannot be created, as shown by the following error.

I suggest you look up what `newtype` is for. The whole point of `newtype` is to provide a zero-cost wrapper around an *existing* type. That means you have one and exactly one constructor taking one and exactly one argument (the wrapped value). At compile time, the wrapping and unwrapping operations become NOPs.

Comment: Ah, I see how my example is using `String` as a data constructor for `B`, not as the type `String`.

Comment: I notice that the type constructor for functions, `(->)`, like `Void` is another type constructor which has no associated data constructor.

Comment: @mherzl Indeed, you defined a constructor `String` which has the same name as the type, but is completely unrelated to it. The functional types `a -> b` also have no constructors: their values are introduced using lambdas `\ x -> ...` (or named function definitions) instead of constructors, and eliminated by application `f x` instead of pattern matching.